# Error 1045 (28000) Cannot stop mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to stop `MySQL` using `sudo mysql stop` command but I'm getting

```
Error 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password NO)
```

I've seen some answers in the internet that I need to stop `MySQL` and update the password but my initial problem was I'm having an error in stopping `MySQL`.

Answer (score 1):

To stop the MySQL service you should do

```
sudo service mysqld stop
```

With `mysql stop` you are trying to connect to a database called `stop`, with your current user and no password.

Comment: Unit mysqld.service not loaded :(

Comment: Try `mariadb` instead of `mysqld`. If it doesn't work either, maybe your database server is not properly installed.

Answer (score 0):

what kind of linux are you using?
you can try

```
    sudo service mysqld stop
```

or in slackware you can try

```
    sudo /etc/rc.d/rc.mysqld stop
```